# Проблема с webpack`ом

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm, webpack4

Есть файлы: 

index.html

Папка script, в которой находятся:

index.js

welcome.js

webpack.config.js

Нужно сделать простую сборку. Открываю командную строку, перехожу в папку с проектом. Пишу `webpack` и командная строка возвращает мне следующее:[image: Проблема со сборкой]

Я пишу yes, начинается установка webpack-cli. После установки, в консоль выводится следующее:[image: Проблема со сборкой]

Что делать? Как установить `webpacl-cli`?

Comment: попробуйте установить глобально
`npm i webpack-cli -g`

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо.